# Magento joining 2 tables

Tags: php, sql, magento

I want to join admin table and another profile table in magento how should I do this?

I want to join `$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');` table and

```
$vendorModel = Mage::getModel('vendorprofile/vendor');
```

Comment: what are the relation key words between two collection???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riaz.try the below code ---

```
           $collection = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection();
    /* start inner join .vendorprofiletable is the 
Mage::getModel('vendorprofile/vendor') module table */
          $collection->getSelect()->join( array('vendorprofile'=> 'vendorprofiletable'), 
        'vendorprofile.vendor_id = main_table.entity_id', array('*'));
```

Here suppose 
`vendorprofile.vendor_id = main_table.entity_id` is the relation  between two tables.

if you want to get query of join then `echo  $collection->getSelect();`

Hope it will be help you.